# Error Connecting to CouchBase from Node.js using Couchnode module v.1.2.4

Tags: node.js, connection, database-connection, couchbase

Using https://github.com/couchbase/couchnode @v.1.2.4

Attempting to connect to CouchBase server using the code in the README

```
var couchbase = require('couchbase');
var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster();
var db = cluster.openBucket('default');

db.set('testdoc', {name:'Frank'}, function(err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;

  db.get('testdoc', function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(result.value);
    // {name: Frank}
  });
});
```

but am getting the following error:

```
db.js:2
var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster();
              ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/n/code/time/test/db.js:2:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
npr:time n$
```

Additional details:

- Running Couchbase Version 2.5.1 on Mac (server appears to be working fine)
- Node Version 0.10.29 (latest)

**Note**: We tried searching on the CouchBase Bug Tracker: http://www.couchbase.com/issues/issues/?jql=text%20~%20%22typeError%22 in case other people were having the same error. No luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "solution" was to use the "Developer Preview" of Couchbase

```
npm install couchbase@2.0.0-dp1
```

Then all the examples on https://github.com/couchbase/couchnode worked as expected.

See: http://blog.couchbase.com/nodejs-sdk-200-developer-preview

Comment: i had to do the same thing, however i feel like this isnt really a fix, are you still using the developer preview?

Comment: Shaun, agree 100%. but the 2.0 is not stable. as soon as it is I will update this answer. thanks.