# "Error: Failed to locate couchnode native binding" on nodejs file

Tags: node.js, express

"Error: Failed to locate couchnode native binding" i get this error when i try to run an express.js file on my terminal. I found here an answer for this problem. [(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451470/trouble-configuring-building-couchnode-on-ubuntu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451470/trouble-configuring-building-couchnode-on-ubuntu)

I did this in the .gyp file and everything went well. But after a day something broke into my node_modules and i the following error again. I changed again the .gyp file then made again the npm rebuild but nothing changed. I still getting this error. Anyone can give me other solution ?

Comment: same issue here, did you managed to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. If you open //node_modules/couchbase/builderror.log file, there is a line that looks for python version "python -V.." and it clearly said that python version SHOULD be > 2.5 and < 3.0

I uninstalled the python 3.4 which was there and installed 2.7.9, then "rm node_modules" --> npm install and voila, no more errors.

Hope this helps.
Cheers!